# How do I see the generated source for Vue SFCs?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm trying to debug a SFC which is giving me an error only on Storybook

> can't access lexical declaration 'backgroundColor' before initialization
>
> setup/<@http://localhost:6006/src/components/SurveyPage.vue?t=1680473980782:17:7
> setVars@http://localhost:6006/node_modules/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-U4ENYQ7M.js?v=7be46031:8910:24

What I want to do is somehow see what that line is but it doesn't seem to map to the file because it gets transformed.  So what I want to see is the transformed output so I can check what's going on.

I tried `vue-tsc ./src/SurveyPage.vue` but I get

> js emit is not supported

I also tried  `npx vue-tsc --noEmit  ./src/Survey.vue`

and got

> error TS6054: File 'src/Survey.vue' has an unsupported extension. The only supported
> extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.cts', '.d.cts', '.mts', '.d.mts'.
>
> The file is in the program because:
>
> Root file specified for compilation